# setw() - adjustfield (left, right or internal)

Tags: field, setf

I am going though the string functions doing tests to learn them (I am a newbie programmer)

Anyway, I am currently looking at [setw()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/) but I seam to not understand it... I think I understand the basic use and the use of setfil

here is my test code
http://ideone.com/czAXH

Anyway the cplusplus website says.. "format flag adjustfield (left, right or internal)" but doesn't say how to use this?

I assume this means I can do the above code but place the "spacing" after the word instead of before it..

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
std::cout << std::left     
    << "[" << std::setw(3) << 1 << "," << std::setw(5) << -100 << "]\n";
std::cout << std::internal 
    << "[" << std::setw(3) << 1 << "," << std::setw(5) << -100 << "]\n";
std::cout << std::right    
    << "[" << std::setw(3) << 1 << "," << std::setw(5) << -100 << "]\n";
```

Outputs:

```
[1  ,-100 ]
[  1,- 100]
[  1, -100]
```